# Postgresql recursive query

Tags: postgresql

I have table with self-related foreign keys and can not get how I can receive firs child or descendant which meet condition. My_table structure is:

| id | parent_id | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | union |
| 2 | 1 | group |
| 3 | 2 | group |
| 4 | 3 | depart |
| 5 | 1 | depart |
| 6 | 5 | unit |
| 7 | 1 | unit |

I should for id 1 (union) receive all direct child or first descendant, excluding all groups between first descendant and union. So in this example as result I should receive:

| id | type |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | depart |
| 5 | depart |
| 7 | unit |

id 4 because it's connected to union through group with id 3 and group with id 2 and id 5 because it's connected directly to union.

I've tried to write recursive query with condition for recursive part: when parent_id = 1 or parent_type = 'depart' but it doesn't lead to expected result

```
  with recursive cte AS (
  select b.id, p.type_id
  from my_table b 
  join my_table p on p.id = b.parent_id
  where b.id = 1

  union
 
  select c.id, cte.type_id      
  from my_table c
  join cte on cte.id = c.parent_id
  where c.parent_id = 1 or cte.type_id = 'group'
 )
```

Comment: What do you mean by "first descendant"? Rows are not ordered in the relational model (unless you explicitly order them by something).

Comment: I mean that it can be direct link between parent record and child, so it will be child, or it can be connection through several records, so the record I should get as result of query not direct child, but descendant.

Comment: So you want the closest descendant that is not of type `group`? But you don't want to get *all* the descendants?

Comment: yes, it's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my interpretation:

1. if `type='group'`, then `id` and `parent_id` are considered in the same group
2. `id#1` and `id#2` are in the same group, they're equals
3. `id#2` and `id#3` are in the same group, they're equals
4. `id#1`, `id#2` and `id#3` are in the same group

If the above is correct, you want to get all the first descendent of `id#1`'s group. The way to do that:

1. Get all the `id`s in the same group with `id#1`
2. Get all the first descendants of the above group (`type not in ('union', 'group')`)

[image]

```sql
with recursive cte_group as (
select 1 as id
union all
select m.id
  from my_table m
  join cte_group g
    on m.parent_id = g.id
   and m.type = 'group')
select mt.id, 
       mt.type
  from my_table mt
  join cte_group cg
    on mt.parent_id = cg.id
   and mt.type not in ('union','group');
```

Result:

```
id|type  |
--+------+
 4|depart|
 5|depart|
 7|unit  |
```

Comment: Thank you. It's so clear in the  end. You understood everything right and your solution is working fine)

Comment: Instead of `mt.type not in ('union','group')`, I would have suggested `mt.id NOT IN TABLE cte_group`

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to start with the row of id `1`, then get its children, and continue recursively on rows of type `group`. To do that, use

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree AS (
  SELECT b.id, b.type, TRUE AS skip
  FROM my_table b
  WHERE id = 1
UNION ALL
  SELECT c.id, c.type, (c.type = 'group') AS skip
  FROM my_table c
  JOIN tree p ON c.parent_id = p.id AND p.skip
)
SELECT id, type
FROM tree
WHERE NOT skip
```